# Centering CSS Slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow, centering

I have a CSS slideshow which currently is left aligned, that I am trying to center within the page. Previously I had a slideshow which spanned the entire page and worked fine, but this time around the images only take up a portion of the page, and are mixed between horizontal and vertical photos (all have the same height). I would appreciate if someone could please guide me as to how I can align this slideshow to the center of my page. I have tried many different tweaks, but with no luck. I am pasting my code below. 
Thank you in advance.

**HTML**

```css
#history_slideshow {
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.crossfade2>figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 27s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0%;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('../photos/history_1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay:6s;
  background-image:url('../photos/history_2.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay:12s;
  background-image:url('../photos/history_3.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: url('../photos/history_4.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    opacity:0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="history_slideshow" class="crossfade2">
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_1.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_2.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_3.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_4.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `display:flex` + `height:100vh` on the parent container, a `min-height/min-width` can be wised when whole content is in absolute position.

`align-items` and `justify-content` will manage centering on X,Y axis..

```css
#history_slideshow {
  padding-top: 1%;
  /* update */
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
  /* could be usefull */
  min-height:400px;
  min-width:600px;
  /* end update */
}

.crossfade2>figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 27s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0%;
  
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/200x400/acd&text=history_1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay:6s;
  background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/afd&text=history_2.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay:12s;
  background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/200x400/0cd&text=history_3.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/456&text=history_4.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    opacity:0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="history_slideshow" class="crossfade2">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x400/acd&text=history_1.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/afd&text=history_2.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x400/0cd&text=history_3.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/456&text=history_4.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

---

#### edit

**horizontal centering**

You may use `display` + `margin` on the parent container.

`display:table;` will shrink on the content size, then `margin:auto` for the horizontal centering will do.

You need to keep a single figure in the flow via `position:`<del>`absolute`</del>`relative` to let the container adapt to image size.

```css
#history_slideshow {
  padding-top: 1%;
  /* update for horizontal centering */
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  }
  
  .crossfade2>figure:first-of-type {
  position:relative;
}
  /* end update */


.crossfade2>figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 27s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0%;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/300x200/acd&text=history_1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay:6s;
  background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/300x200/afd&text=history_2.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay:12s;
  background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/300x200/0cd&text=history_3.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2>figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/300x200/456&text=history_4.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    opacity:0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="history_slideshow" class="crossfade2">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/acd&text=history_1.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/afd&text=history_2.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/0cd&text=history_3.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/456&text=history_4.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I tweaked your suggestion a bit and it worked like a charm.  Initially there was a lot of empty space above and below the slideshow. When I edited the height value, it overlapped with the divs above it. I tried adding each line you provided one at a time, and found I only needed: display:flex
and justify-content:center. Thank you.

Comment: @user8385857 okay, so my first understanding was the right one (horizontal centering) , i'll update my answer with the first answer i had. (seeable on edit history)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can center a `<div>`by adding 
`margin: 0 auto`
`width:auto`
`display : inline-block`

Check your code with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `transform` css

```css
#history_slideshow {
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.crossfade2 > figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 27s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.crossfade2 > figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('../photos/history_1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2 > figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay:6s;
  background-image:url('../photos/history_2.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2 > figure:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay:12s;
  background-image:url('../photos/history_3.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.crossfade2 > figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: url('../photos/history_4.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    opacity:0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    opacity:0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    opacity:0;
  }
  8% {
    animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="history_slideshow" class="crossfade2">
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_1.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_2.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_3.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="../photos/history_4.jpg" alt="" />
  </figure>
</div>
```